# Android audiomanager - I want to set silent mode, but applied the priority mode (lollipop)

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-audiomanager

My problem is occurs in android lollipop os.

I want to set 'silent mode', but lollipop os applies to '**priority mode**'. (I use AudioManager) Is there any way I can apply the 'silent mode' instead of 'priority mode'?

My code :

```
AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to changes in API try using the `int` value `0` instead of `AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT`

```
AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
mAudioManager.setRingerMode(0);
```

Also try checking your manifest file

```
<application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on asus 5.o device , got resolved by replacing RINGER_MODE_SILENT with RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE. this might be strange but worked best for me .

```
AudioManager audiomanage = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audiomanage.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
```